# How to EDIT only the last line (or any specific line number(s)) using awk command?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, gawk

I have a big multi columns file with #n number of records (lines). How I can only apply `awk` command in the last record or any specific  records number (*i.g.* NR==4) or a range of lines (NR==[2-5])?

as an example in the following file:

```
echo filename
30.5,2010/06/01,2016/08/29,2281.00,0006.25,0074.94
41.6,2008/03/05,2012/03/05,1461.00,0004.00,0048.00
39.6,2008/03/05,2012/09/10,1649.96,0004.52,0054.21
41.0,2008/03/05,2013/09/16,2020.96,0005.53,0066.40
42.2,2008/03/05,2014/03/18,2203.96,0006.03,0072.41
41.1,2008/03/05,2014/09/16,2385.96,0006.53,0078.39
43.1,2008/05/08,2014/09/16,/2322.00,/0006.36,/0076.29
```

I apply the following awk script to remove  the `/` in any fields except the  dates.

```
nawk -F, -v OFS=,  '{split($4,a,"/"); $4=sprintf("%06.2f", a[2]);split ($5,b,"/");$5=sprintf("%06.2f", b[2]);split($6,c,"/");$6=sprintf("%06.2f", c[2]); print $0}' filename
```

Although it is correct for the last line but adversely impact on the  other lines which do not have `/`. Following output:

```
output

30.5,2010/06/01,2016/08/29,000.00,000.00,000.00
41.6,2008/03/05,2012/03/05,000.00,000.00,000.00
39.6,2008/03/05,2012/09/10,000.00,000.00,000.00
41.0,2008/03/05,2013/09/16,000.00,000.00,000.00
42.2,2008/03/05,2014/03/18,000.00,000.00,000.00
41.1,2008/03/05,2014/09/16,000.00,000.00,000.00
43.1,2008/05/08,2014/09/16,2322.00,006.36,076.29


however, the expected correct output should be :

30.5,2010/06/01,2016/08/29,2281.00,0006.25,0074.94
41.6,2008/03/05,2012/03/05,1461.00,0004.00,0048.00
39.6,2008/03/05,2012/09/10,1649.96,0004.52,0054.21
41.0,2008/03/05,2013/09/16,2020.96,0005.53,0066.40
42.2,2008/03/05,2014/03/18,2203.96,0006.03,0072.41
41.1,2008/03/05,2014/09/16,2385.96,0006.53,0078.39
43.1,2008/05/08,2014/09/16,2322.00,0006.36,0076.29
```

So, how I can tell awk to only apply this in the last line or any specific line number(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As awk processes the file, the variable **`NR`** represents the total number of records processed.  So you need only add a *pattern* such as

```
(NR == 5)
```

before your *action*

```
{split($4,a,"/");...
```

e.g.,

```
(NR == 5){split($4,a,"/");...
```

to process line 5.

If you want to process the *last* line only, then you can save the line in the default action

```
{ save = $0; }
```

and process that line in the `END` section.  But you'll have to do field splitting there (`$0` no longer applies):

```
END {split(whatever,a,"/");...
```

For a range, you would use a more complicated expression,

```
( NR >= 2 && NR <= 5 )
```

to select rows 2 through 5.

Further reading:

- [expressions in awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02) (POSIX)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Can you please tell me two more things: How does it work in terms of the range of records? for instance lines 5 till 15?                                                                                                          In addition, can you please write the whole awk script for the last line for me. Tnx

Comment: IIRC - `END` containing the last row doesn't work for all (most but not all) versions of `awk`. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND.html

Comment: You should always get `END`, and if (as noted) **save** the value in the default action, that's available for use in the `END` action.